# How to generate random Std_logic_vector in vhdl?

Tags: vector, vhdl

I need to generate a random 12b vector in VHDL, but vector(2 down to 0), vector (5 downto 3), etc. can have value from 001 to 101. I don't have idea how to do it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: For simulation or hardware?
For simulation, have a look at OSVVM: osvvm.org
For synthesis on hardware, look up LFSR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: OSVVM is available on github at https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM